# react-native-video player goes in buffer mode and taking long time to laod video. I am using snap carousel library

Tags: react-native, react-native-video, react-native-snap-carousel

I am using react-native-video with react-native-snap-carousel because I want to show full screen video with vertical scroll like tik-tok. Sometimes videos goes in buffer mode and taking very long time to load video and sometimes it is not loading and if I scroll in between then other video stops loading. Can anyone tell me how to fix it. Releasing video while scrolling will work? If yes how can I release video player. If video is in buffering mode and if it is taking long time to load, is there any way I can resolve it(maybe pause/play video). When it goes in buffering mode, I logged it but after few times log is not printing and even no error.

Comment: Is your video hosted in a good hosting provider? I was using react-native-video, but due a bad shared host, the video was buffering slowly.

Comment: I have the exact same issue on RN app. I started tests using the AWS architecure https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/video-on-demand-on-aws/.  No success yet.